# iterate over a file in a growing folder in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, directory

I want to iterate over all the files in a folder in python.

Further, it is given that the folder is growing, i.e. files are added to it asynchronously. Whenever I am iterating, I am doing some operation.

So Assume that the time taken for that operation is more than downloading speed that means I will not finish iterating before the downloading ends.

If there is any way to do that, please suggest. You can always start again so please don't suggest that method.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(".") if isfile(join(".",f)) ]

for s in onlyfiles:
    #dosomething
```

Comment: Maybe keep a set of all the files you've visited?  Post some code showing some solutions you've tried.

Comment: I have edited and added the code that i am using for traversing the folder now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use python `set`s to build a list of files you've already processed and then cycle through the directory some number of times until you are comfortable that you have seen all of the current batch of files.

Something like:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import os
 import time

 processed = set()
 tripsWithNoChange = 0
 timeToLetWriterCatchUp = 2
 maxNumberOfTrips = 10

 while tripsWithNoChange < maxNumberOfTrips:
     for root,dirs,files in os.walk('.'):
         candidates = set(files)

         # remove the files already visited from consideration
         candidates.difference_update(processed)

         if len(candidates) == 0:
             tripsWithNoChange += 1
             continue

         for f in candidates:
             # process file
             pass

         processed.update(candidates)

         time.sleep(timeToLetWriterCatchUp)
```

There are several `magic` numbers in this approach that you will need to tune until you are confident that all the files are processed, specifically:

- tripsWithNoChange
- timeToLetWriterCatchUp
- maxNumberOfTrips

Maybe this will give you some ideas.